# How can i change the height of a grid in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, grid

How can i change the height of a grid of a Piechart in Primefaces?

```
function skinPie() {
                this.cfg.shadow = false;
                this.cfg.title = '';               
                this.cfg.grid = {
                    background: '#ffffff',
                    borderColor: '#ffffff',
                    gridLineColor: '#F5F5F5',                   
                    shadow: false,                                                
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you meant about the height of grid of a pieChart, but here are  some configurations for sizing it:

```
this.cfg.gridPadding = {top: 0, bottom: 10, left: 0, right: 0};
this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {shadow: true, 
                           renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                           rendererOptions: {
                                             fill: false,
                                             sliceMargin: 4,
                                             diameter: 250,
                                             gridLineWidth: 1.0,
                                             showDataLabels: true
                                            }
                          }
```

Please, let me know if that was what you wanted or, in case if it's not, explain me about what you need.